# ORACLE Group query by week, month and year

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a bunch of queries that take data with a time stamp and spit out SUMS based the last few weeks, months, and year to date. It looks like this

```
Week1    Sum for most recent week
Week2    Sum for second most recent week
WeekN    Sum for N most recent week
Jan-Dec  Sum for January-December
YTD      Sum for everything this year
```

This is how the query currently does this

```
SELECT TIME_PERIOD, INDEX, SUM(ITEM)   
FROM (SELECT
        INDEX ,
        (CASE  
            WHEN ACTIVITY_DAY>=(TO_DATE( :end_day,
            'yyyy-mm-dd' )-6)  
            AND ACTIVITY_DAY<=(TO_DATE( :end_day,
            'yyyy-mm-dd' )-0) THEN 'WEEK1'  
            WHEN ACTIVITY_DAY>=(TO_DATE( :end_day,
            'yyyy-mm-dd' )-13)  
            AND ACTIVITY_DAY<=(TO_DATE( :end_day,
            'yyyy-mm-dd' )-7) THEN 'WEEK2'  
            ELSE NULL  
        END) AS TIME_PERIOD,
        MAX(ITEMS) AS ITEM
    FROM
        SOURCE  
    GROUP BY
        INDEX ,
        DAY  
    UNION
    ALL SELECT
        INDEX ,
        (CASE  
            WHEN ACTIVITY_DAY>=TO_DATE( :year||'-01-01',
            'yyyy-mm-dd' )  
            AND ACTIVITY_DAY<=TO_DATE( :year||'-01-31',
            'yyyy-mm-dd' ) THEN 'Jan'  
            WHEN ACTIVITY_DAY>=TO_DATE( :year||'-02-01',
            'yyyy-mm-dd' )  
            AND ACTIVITY_DAY<TO_DATE( :year||'-03-01',
            'yyyy-mm-dd' ) THEN 'Feb'   
            ELSE NULL  
        END) AS TIME_PERIOD ,
        MAX(ITEMS) AS ITEM
    FROM
        SOURCE  
    GROUP BY
        INDEX ,
        DAY  
    UNION
    ALL SELECT
        INDEX ,
        (CASE  
            WHEN ACTIVITY_DAY>=TO_DATE( :year||'-01-01',
            'yyyy-mm-dd' )  
            AND ACTIVITY_DAY<=TO_DATE( :end_day,
            'yyyy-mm-dd' ) THEN 'YTD'  
            ELSE NULL  
        END) AS TIME_PERIOD,
        MAX(ITEMS) AS ITEM
    FROM
        SOURCE  
    GROUP BY
        INDEX ,
        DAY)
GROUP BY INDEX, TIME_PERIOD
```

Is there a better way in Oracle?

Comment: I'm not seeing any `SUM` in your query.  Are you trying to generate one row with various columns for the various sums?  Or are you trying to generate multiple rows with the sum for that time_period?  Is the N in the "N most recent weeks" known?  Or is that specified at runtime?  Are you trying to get N rows (or N columns), one per week?  Or a cumulative sum of the last N weeks?  Which January-December are you trying to pick?  If you run the query in November 2011, would you have November and December 2011 totals (presumably 0)?  Or would you go back to 2010 for that?

Comment: Fixed the query so it should be more clear. There should only be one row per time_period and Index. Week N is just there to indicate that there are more weeks in the history for the real query. January-December just indicates that there's a by month history starting with January and going all the way to December, so there would be TIME_PERIODs = Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, ... , Dec. For Nov 11 and Dec 11 the query currently just returns nothing. We don't need to go back to 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
with data as
(
    select sysdate - floor(dbms_random.value(1,400)) dt, floor(dbms_random.value(1,100)) val
    from dual
    connect by level <= 100
)
select
    time_period,
    sum(val) period_sum
from
(
    select -- weeks
        'Week'||(to_char(sysdate, 'WW') - to_char(dt, 'WW') + 1) time_period,
        val,
        (to_char(sysdate, 'WW') - to_char(dt, 'WW') + 1) ord
    from data
    where dt >= trunc(sysdate,'YY')
    union all
    select -- months
        to_char(dt, 'Mon') time_period,
        val,
        100+to_char(dt,'MM') ord
    from data
    where dt >= trunc(sysdate,'YY')
    union all
    select -- months
        'YTD' time_period,
        val,
        200
    from data
    where dt >= trunc(sysdate,'YY')
)
group by
    time_period, ord
order by
    ord;
```

Note that you won't need the WITH block, I was just using it to create some dummy data.  The Ord column might be unnecessary for you, I was just using it to order the data in a logical fashion.